# Taking Datastage project backup via shell script using export command

Tags: shell-exec, datastage

I'm using shell script for taking datastage project backup.

I'm using this command for taking backup

```
/apps/IBM/InformationSever/server/DSengine/istool export –domain eltappsrvonoi:9080 -username user1 -password pass1     -archive "\tmp\arc.isx"  -datastage  '
"eltappengprnoi:5000/ITDCPC_SIT/Jobs/*/*.*"  '
```

This command working fine and successfully completed when I'm giving hard code value as project name(ITDCPC_SIT).

When adding variable name as project name in shell script and taking value at the execution time.

```
/apps/IBM/InformationSever/server/DSengine/istool export –domain eltappsrvonoi:9080 -username user1 -password pass1 -archive "\tmp\arc.isx"  -datastage  '
"eltappengprnoi:5000/$PROJECTNAME/Jobs/*/*.*"  '
```

It's giving error :

> Project Name not Found. (I'm giving right value. no mistake in projectname)

Comment: i found solution .....

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else wondering about that problem:

Just use double quotes instead of single ones, as variables are not replaced otherwise. Don't forget to escape the inner double quotes!

```
/apps/IBM/InformationSever/server/DSengine/istool export –domain eltappsrvonoi:9080 -username user1 -password pass1 -archive "\tmp\arc.isx"  -datastage  
"  \"eltappengprnoi:5000/$PROJECTNAME/Jobs/*/*.*\"  "
```

always bad to have a question unsolved....